# Can I do an if else in a Javascript forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, foreach

Learner here! I'm trying to create a (name) search for an html table with a list of people. I've given each row in the table body an id of `row-body` and a data-attribute of `data-name`. For each row, I want to check if the search text can be found in the name, and if so, the row should show. Otherwise, the row should hide.
Here's my code. How can I implement the if/else?

```
    $("#search-box").on('keyup', function () {

        const search = $("#search-box").val();

        $("#body-row").forEach($("#body-row"), if (CheckMatch($(this).data("name"), search)) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        })

    function CheckMatch(n, s) {
        const name = n.toLowerCase();
        const search = s.toLowerCase();
        return name.includes(search);
    }
```

Comment: No, you can't pass an `if` statement around. You must pass a callback function. Of course you may put `if`/`else` inside that function. Notice however that it's in most cases much easier to use `for … of` loops than `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to use classes instead of IDs - duplicate IDs in a single document is invalid HTML.

While you could do it just by writing a proper callback (using the proper name, `.each` - `.forEach` is for arrays and Sets and Maps, not jQuery objects):

```
$(".body-row").each(function() {
  if (CheckMatch($(this).data("name"), search)) {
    $(this).show();
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

It'd be easier to use [`.toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$(".body-row").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(CheckMatch($(this).data("name"), search));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> A small snippet for other SO users to understand the question and solution easily.

```js
$("#search-box").on("keyup", function() {

  let searchVal = $("#search-box").val();
  $(".list-item").each(function() {
    if (checkMatch(searchVal, $(this).text())) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }

    // $(this).toggle(checkMatch(searchVal, $(this).text()))
  });
});


function checkMatch(val, item) {
  return item.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-box">

<ul>
  <li class="list-item">Apple</li>
  <li class="list-item">Mango</li>
  <li class="list-item">Banana</li>
  <li class="list-item">Berry</li>
  <li class="list-item">Appricot</li>
  <li class="list-item">Grapes</li>
  <li class="list-item">Guava</li>
  <li class="list-item">Watermelon</li>
  <li class="list-item">Melon</li>
  <li class="list-item">Pineapple</li>
</ul>
```